# Why does it work in development but not on live server?

Tags: php, mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have developed a working system on Xampp but when I transfer it to Server 2008 r2 I run into trouble. I have installed MySql 5.5.42 successfully and can login as root user through command line and pma. I have developed a web form in PHP which stores the field data in MySql but I am receiving a querying error now that my files are in use on the server & the data is not reaching MySql server. It works without any problem on my development machine.

I am using ‘localhost’ in my DB connection statements. I have also verified all passwords & user names are correct. I have verified that PHP is also installed. My index.php page is reachable by clients without problem. Where it is falling down is the connection between PHP web form & MySql.

Sever management isn't my strong point and I’m hoping someone has come across this issue & has a solution or helpful tips.

DB connection

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'dataBase')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
```

insert data to table

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, " .
    "column_5, column _6, column_7) " .
    "VALUES ('$column_1', '$column_2', '$column_3', '$column_4','$column_5', " .
             "'$column_6, '$column_7')";
```

Result, the error I receive is 'Error querying database'

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error querying database.');
```

Comment: can you show us the code??

Comment: exact error message also.

Comment: Have you tried using ```127.0.0.1```

Comment: Hi Justin, yes I have tried 127.0.0.1 but I have the same error

Comment: Arkoak, this is the exact error message I recieve. "localhost via TCP/IP Error querying database"

Comment: That's the error you're printing out yourself though, which is going to confuse things. Are these column names real or have you made them up for the question? If they're real, then it's going to be the fact you have an extra space in "column _6" which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Instead of `die('Error querying database.');` you can use `die(var_dump(mysqli_error($dbc)));`, you'll then see the actual error that occurred.

Comment: Hi Cristik, the error I recieve now is  -  string(61) "Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'Lasermark_2' at row 1"

Answer (score 0):

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=DATABASENAME; UID=USERNAME;PASSWORD=PASSWORD;
```

**in your coniguration:**
Check if you have set proper version of ODBC

**in your query:**
change localhost to 127.0.0.1 (or other probable IP of server for localhost)

Comment: I am installing ODBC 64bit as we speak Ali. I will let you know how I get on, thanks.

Comment: It hasn't helped me I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you using a CMS? can you add codes that your configuration file tries to connect to database?

Comment: I'm not using a CMS Ali, code to connect to DB is: $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'DB')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

Comment: It all works fine in xampp on development machine. Something I'm missing or not doing on live server that's causing the error.

Comment: Have you created a username and password for mysql database? **root** is default username on xampp where you need creating username and password through control panel on server.

Comment: Hi Ali, yes I have setup MySql with same details as xampp. root as user and I have used the same password.

Comment: Currently in my php.ini file "mysqli.default_socket" is = to noting/ blank. Could this be part of the problem?